# Footer not getting placed at correct place

Tags: html, css

I am not that good in CSS. I am trying to make a HTML structure but I am not able to get the footer at the correct place. Here is a [link](http://dabblet.com/gist/5316936) where you can see and test the code. Can you please suggest something. I must say I dont want the footer div to get `position:fixed` option.

Comment: where you want to place footer ? what is correct place ? 
Ohh I think I got it. You want it below content area.

Comment: use float:left; in footer

Comment: why don't you want to use `position:fixed`? see this support chart http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed

Comment: @crazyrohila: yes . below the content area

Comment: @JanTuroň: `position: fixed` makes the site ugly when I am at the top of the page

Comment: @Roger you should use float and clear for this layout. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hN9S9/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the position of id `#placeHolder`  and `footer_area` and add css

```
#placeHolder {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    width: 70%;
}


.footer_area {
    background-position: 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    clear: both;
    color: #333333;
    font: 12px/25px Arial,Helvetica;
    height: 10%;
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    padding-top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things that may help you better understand how CSS works is how relative, absolute, static, and fixed works.

For a quick brush up you can check here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

By default all of your elements are positioned statically and all elements inherit their positioning in a hierarchical pattern. I.E. First element in the DOM comes first then the following etc.

In this case you have positioned your #placeholder element with a position:absolute; the result is the #placeholder is ripped out of sequence from the other elements and placed outside it's order it is now respecting the body tag and takes it's placement relative to the body tag. The only exception here is if you modify a parent element of #placeholder with the position:relative then the #placeholder will take an absolute positioning relative to that element instead of the body element.

Secondly I can see that you are trying to achieve an alignment of your elements close to the center of the window using a percentage base. In this case 15%, this is not going to give you an absolute center for your content. What happens is 15% of current window width (lets pretend my browser is opened to 1000px wide) will return 15% of the current window width in this case 150px; in essence you end up positioning the left of the element 150px from the left of the window.

Furthermore; having to place this positioning on all elements can become a bit cumbersome. A little trick that will make your life easier is to wrap all of your content in a div and class this div. I will usually class it as `<div class="wrapper">` then in your css you can give .wrapper a width of 1000px or 70% in your case and a **margin:0 auto;** this will automatically center the contents of this div for you and therefore center your site. If you would like to make it work for really old browsers keep the same content I have demonstrated only add two more properties. The first CSS property to the **body{text-align:center;}** and the second to **.wrapper{text-align:left;}**. This will make it work in IE6 if you even still care about ie6. What it does is aligns the first `<div class="wrapper">` to the center of body but then specifies that all content within wrapper should be aligned left this makes it so when you add dom elements or text it's nicely aligned to the left so you can read it normally.

Hope this helps